# Folder permissions through a web page?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, permissions

I want a folder on a site where logged-in active directory users can create sub folders and upload images under an "/Uploads" folder off the root. I am able to retrieve the username using System.DirectoryServices.

Is there a way to:

1. Restrict what is returned from the DirectoryInfo().GetDirectories based on their username
2. Set permissions on a subfolder of /Uploads (via a web page) to read/write.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look at this post on [how to create folder dynamically at run time](http://forums.asp.net/t/1360137.aspx/1)

And [this post from stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2266934/how-to-set-folder-permissions-with-net) shows bunch of ways to assign folder permissions. See which one applies

Good luck!